# Python - Extracting text from HTML element

Tags: python

I am trying to extract text from an HTML element that is written by a JS script upon login to the site.
By making a request via python I am only getting the DOM with the empty element printed on the screen. Is there any way to extract the updated text? I tried via selenium but you have to have the browser window on the screen, otherwise a blank line is printed.
This is the DOM with the script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
<script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="coordinates"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("coordinates");
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
function showPosition(position) {
 x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + " Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to use something like Selenium WebDriver to execute the JS.

Comment: it's also possible to sometimes log in by sending a post request with the credentials, then you can save session cookies (just use `requests.Session`) and then with that session request this document and you should get it as you need, that is only if their login system is like that